# Unable to open the default file picker for using Xamarin and Webview to Android App

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview, webchromeclient

I am currently using the Xamarin to build a cross-platform mobile application.
Basically my app only using the webview(*The webview only opens a website that has a upload image function*), for some extract features I have to use the **webchromeclient** for Android. 
After adding setting up the **webchromeclient**, The **webview** can not open the file picker from the android device. (iphone works fine because the webchromeclient has noting to do with IOS path);

Here's the struct for my project

```
---test
     |_ CustomWebView.cs
     |_ MainPage.xaml
     |_ MainPage.cs
---test.Android
     |_ MainActivity.cs
     |_ AndroidCustomWebViewRenderer.cs
---test.IOS
     |_ IOS files
```

**CustomWebView.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public class CustomWebView : WebView
    {
         
    }
}
```

**AndroidCustomWebViewRenderer.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{

    public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control != null)
        {
            Android.Webkit.WebView webView = this.Control;
            webView.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);


            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
            webView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;


            webView.SetWebChromeClient(new TestWebViewClient());
          
        }
    }

    public class TestWebViewClient : Android.Webkit.WebChromeClient
    {
        
        public override bool OnShowFileChooser(Android.Webkit.WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
           
            return base.OnShowFileChooser(webView, filePathCallback, fileChooserParams);

        }



        public override bool OnConsoleMessage(Android.Webkit.ConsoleMessage consoleMessage)
        {
            Log.Debug("WebViewConsole", $"{consoleMessage.Message()}");
            return base.OnConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
        }


    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
namespace test.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "test", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

    }
}
```

And the AndroidManifest.xml has all the permissions for accessing the Storage.
So I assume that something wrong with the webchromeclient that missing something for opening the default file picker from android.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following code into the TestWebViewClient:

```
public class TestWebViewClient : Android.Webkit.WebChromeClient
{
        public static int filechooser = 1;
        public static IValueCallback message;


        public override bool OnShowFileChooser(global::Android.Webkit.WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            message = filePathCallback;
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            chooserIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            chooserIntent.SetType("*/*");
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(chooserIntent, "File Chooser"), filechooser);
            return true;
        }
}
```

And in the MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(data !=null)
        {
            if (requestCode == MyWebChromeClient.filechooser)
            {
                if(MyWebChromeClient.message !=null)
                {
                    TestWebViewClient.message.OnReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.ParseResult((int)resultCode, data));
                    TestWebViewClient.message = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```